# How to apply automatic discount in WooCommerce using dollar amount variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

In my attempt to find a solution for dollar amount based automatic coupon I am encountering the following problem. First the rules:

1. If dollar amount less than 53 do nothing.
2. If dollar amount greater than 53 and less than 90 apply "couponX"
3. If dollar amount greater than 90 apply "couponY"

I have been able to get the code to work with the second (2) rule of the code. However the third rule will not be applied. My code below. Any thoughts?

```
// Add coupon when user views cart before checkout
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'add_coupon_automatically');
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'add_coupon_automatically');

// Check if function? create it.
if (!function_exists('add_coupon_automatically')) {
function add_coupon_automatically() {
global $woocommerce;
$eleven = '20plus';
$four = '10plus';
$eleven_minimum = 179;
$four_minimum = 89;

if($woocommerce->cart->get_cart()->cart_contents_total>$eleven_minimum) {
// Apply 20plus
if (!$woocommerce->cart->add_discount( sanitize_text_field( $eleven )))
$woocommerce->add_message('20 Plus coupon (11%) automatically applied!');
$woocommerce->show_messages();
//Recalculate totals
 $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
} elseif ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart()->cart_contents_total<$eleven_minimum 
  && $woocommerce->cart->get_cart()->cart_contents_total>$four_minimum) {
// Apply 10plus
if (!$woocommerce->cart->add_discount( sanitize_text_field( $four )))
$woocommerce->add_message('10 Plus coupon (4%) automatically applied!');
$woocommerce->show_messages();
//Recalculate totals
$woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
}
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was going about it the wrong way. Seems the best approach was to base it on cart Item quantity rather than price.

New rules:

1. Create coupons with minimum of 10 / 20 quantities.
2. Add to `child_theme/woocommerce/cart.php`

   ```
   global $count_cart_quantity;
   $count_cart_quantity = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
   ```
3. Finally apply the coupons via hook

   ```
   add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_20');
   function discount_20() {
   global $woocommerce;
   global $count_cart_quantity;
   if ( $count_cart_quantity > 19 ) {
   $coupon_code = '20plus';
   if (!$woocommerce->cart->add_discount(sanitize_text_field($coupon_code))) {
       $woocommerce->show_messages();
   }
   echo '<div classs"woocommerce_message"><strong>
   You qualified for an 11% discount and it has been applied!</strong>
   </div>';
   }
   }

   add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_10');
   function discount_10() {
   global $woocommerce;
   global $count_cart_quantity;
   if ( $count_cart_quantity < 20 && $count_cart_quantity > 9 ) {
   $coupon_code = '10plus';
   if (!$woocommerce->cart->add_discount(sanitize_text_field($coupon_code))) {
       $woocommerce->show_messages();
   }
   echo '<div classs"woocommerce_message"><strong>
   You qualified for an 4% discount and it has been applied!</strong>
   </div>';
   }
   }
   ```

Now it works well!

Answer (score 0):

You could change

```
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart()->cart_contents_total
```

to

```
$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total
```

then your function will work.